# How to add the projects of other solution to a newly created solution?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, windows-installer, setup-project

I have created a setup project MyApplicationFull and i want to add the projects of my other two application MyApp1 & MyApp2, this should also include the setup.exe of both MyApp1 & MyApp2. How can i add all the projects and setup.exe's to MyApplicationFull and this on run should install two applications(MyApp1 & MyApp2).

I use .net 4.0 , WinForms,c#

thanks in advance

It throws this error when i debug. I thought there must be some wrong in the procedure i did.

```
error C1189: #error :  This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h ,MyApp2AddInShim
```

Answer (score 2):

in the Solution Explorer right click on the solution, and select Add Existing Project...

Comment: @Zdravko-Error 1 error C1189: #error :  This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended. c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h ,MyApp2AddInShim

Comment: try starting with an empty solution and adding all projects to it.

Comment: Should i use the setup project template to start the solution? I just elected the template "setup Project" from the setup & deployment project types. And on clicking right on the "solution", i started adding the projects.

Comment: go to file, new project, other project types, visual studio solution. then add all the projects to it...

Comment: can i create one setup.exe file name MyApplicationFull to this that can install both MyApp1 and MyApp2 at a single run ?